# firebase deployment issue with a react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to deploy my react app on firebase but i get this error:

> Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.

***and in the ***firebase-debug.log*** file this shows:***

[info] First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.

[info] You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,

[info] but for now we'll just set up a default project.

[info]
[debug] [2021-03-20T19:18:31.200Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: []

[debug] [2021-03-20T19:18:31.202Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token

[debug] [2021-03-20T19:18:32.948Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"expires":"Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00
GMT","cache-control":"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","date":"Sat, 20 Mar 2021 19:18:28 GMT","pragma":"no-cache","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","server":"scaffolding on HTTPServer2","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[debug] [2021-03-20T19:18:33.023Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects pageSize=100

[debug] [2021-03-20T19:18:35.619Z] Failed to make request: invalid json response body at https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects?pageSize=100 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

[debug] [2021-03-20T19:18:37.235Z] FirebaseError: Failed to make request: invalid json response body at https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects?pageSize=100 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at Client.request (C:\Users\john tucker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\apiv2.js:109:19)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

[error]
[error] Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.

***I have already tried to logout and login and made sure that my app exists in the firebase console .***

***I also get this error when I type firebase init in the terminal :***

(node:12720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FirebaseError: Failed to make request to https://firebase-public.firebaseio.com/cli.json
at Client.doRequest (C:\Users\john tucker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\apiv2.js:211:19)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

(node:12720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

(node:12720) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow this steps to deploy your react app online with fire-base hosting :

```
    npm run build => Run the following command to create a build directory with a production build of your app
 
    npm install -g firebase-tools => To host your site with Firebase Hosting, you need the Firebase command-line tool (CLI). Run the following npm command to install the CLI on your system globally

    firebase login => If you're not logged in, you'll be asked to enter the credentials for your google account.

    firebase init => to initialize firebase in your react app

    firebase deploy => Firebase will now run the deploying process and will give you a unique URL where your app is deployed
```

Comment: thank you dear sir for taking the time to help , i did exactly what you said but i got the same error again and when i type : firebase init  , this comes out on the terminal please look again at the post because the error showing in the terminal didn't fit here :(